# Highcharts in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

I am using `Highcharts` but it is not working.
Here is my code

View.php

```
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    </div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () { 
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>                   

    @stop
```

Is there anything to add? Totally confused.

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js`?

Comment: what is the error showing in console?

Comment: Thanks for ur time ,actually it was my mistake i included the script twice in my code..